# How to resolve package error in android studio

Tags: android

I want to create a `face api` using Microsoft. I created an application using android studio but when building it, I got the below error.

> Could not resolve com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.0.0.

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Add dependencies in `build.gradle` file properly. Sync project.

You can try adding following

```
compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **build.gradle** file in your 'app' project.
2. Add a dependency for client library stored in maven central
   repository .

Then add this

```
dependencies {  

    compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.0.0'  
             }
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Sync** your Project .

Courtesy goes to **[Configure the Face API client library](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api/documentation/Get-Started-with-Face-API/GettingStartedwithFaceAPIinJavaforAndroid)**

Comment: I already add this dependency in my build.gradle file in  'app'. from where i download client library and how it include in classpath using android studio.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.0.0'
}

Comment: add this `allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        mavenCentral()
    }
}` ????

Comment: I get error at import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton can not resolve symbol